# SG3525 feedback identification

Tags: pwm, inverter, feedback, flyback, duty-cycle

This is from a UPS which creates 350VDC from 12VDC, How does this arrangement work to control presumably the duty cycle of SG3525?

Compensation (pin 9) and inverting input (pin 1) are connected directly together, non-inverting input (pin 2) is connected to the optocoupler and has a 5k+5k voltage divider to VCC, which at 12 V from battery would create 6 V which should be under 5 V?

I tried looking for similar designs but failed to find one, if powered, circuit does create under 100 VDC on the output that slowly climb in 10 seconds or so.

I know there is a sawtooth oscillation that is compared with error amplifier, if Non Inverting input is pulled low duty cycle should decrease but I am already getting barely any output. Please help me understand this design.

**Update**: Managed to trace it using bright light under pcb and scratching traces at possible paths. Now schematic is more accurate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frDOE8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Something is not correct in the schematic. As drawn, it would regulate the 5 V rail to (2.5/4k)*4.4k + 2.5 = 5.25 V. Please double check.

Comment: that part has about 10 miles of pcb traces going back and forth to microcontroller and tl072 opamp, non of which have reasonable resistance to flyback, after hours or tracing i deemed it untraceable @winny so i thought about asking here to get insights which would point me right traces to probe

Comment: @winny updated schematics after hard work, now they kinda make sense, still need guidance on function

Comment: Good. Should regulate to 378.75 V.

Answer (score 0):

At the SG3525, with no current flowing into the output of the opto, R3 (5k) & R4 (5k) will cause pin 2 to be at 6V (higher than the 5.1V Vref at pin 8), which causes the SG3525 to output pulses at maximum pulse-width.

The TL431 with R1 (602k) & R2 (4k) as shown will allow current to pass in the LED of the opto when "High voltage" is above 378V.  Below that voltage, the opto LED current will be very low.  Above that voltage, the LED current increases, which then causes current to flow into the output pin of the opto from the join of R3 & R4, which causes the voltage at SG3525 pin 2 to reduce, causing the voltage at pin 9 to match the voltage at pin 2, which causes the pulse widths to reduce.  This then causes the output voltage to reduce, until the system reaches equilibrium under negative feedback where the current in the opto LED is at the required level to cause the pulse widths to remain constant.

Note, however, that the LED current is drawn from the capacitor marked as 35V 100uF.  That voltage is probably coming from an aux winding on the main power transformer, which is controlled by the SG3525 output pulses.  If that is the case, then there will be no LED current until the voltage on the cap exceeds the cathode voltage of TL431 plus the forward voltage of the opto LED.

**Question:**
Where does the power for the SG3525 come from?  This is marked as an ideal "+12V" source in the schematic, but is that really the case?  Perhaps this being generated from, say, a bleed resistor from a high-voltage source?  If that is the case, then I would look there first, to make sure the SG3525 has a good power supply during the start-up process.

Comment: That is a failed logic question, sg3525 is the one creating those high voltages and is powered by battery, there might be a boost regulator first but if it is not powered there will be no high voltage hence nothing to power sg3525, I powered it directly from 12v battery

Comment: That 35v are coming from isolated power supply generated by uc3845 and is under 18v

Comment: Is your question regarding how the US3525 works, or how to fix the problem you have? 

You stated: " if Non Inverting input is pulled low duty cycle should decrease..."  CORRECT.

 You stated: "... but I am already getting barely any output. "  

Without more information we cannot help you solve this problem.

Comment: "That 35v are coming from isolated power supply generated by uc3845 and is under 18v"

Have you measured this voltage?  What is it?  Can you measure DC voltage with a DMM?  If "yes", then what is the voltage at SG3525 pin Non-inv input?    

Do you have a scope? Can you post waveforms?

Comment: I don't have oscilloscope, uc3845 forms a small boost converter to provide 18v DC power to MCU, Opto and other components, I wanted to know (now just confirm that) tl431 is just only there to reduce high voltage because of the way it is designed here then why my output is not rising like tl431+opto is not responsible in raising output voltage in anyway here right?

Comment: and to confirm, pin2 (non-inv input) has 6v measured with DMM @Fabio

Comment: The schematic does not show the main power circuit, so we cannot tell what circuit is creating the high-voltage (378Vdc) on C1.  The schematic also has to show how the voltage on UC3525 pin Vcc is generated at start-up.  Just putting a battery there may not be sufficient to get the circuit to work as intended.